# C RPG game for my homework

Tags: c

I have problem with declaring dmg and making % chance to hit

```
int oruzije,udarac,neprijatelj,heroj;
while(1) {
    neprijatelj=100;
    heroj=100;
    int rand_int(int n);
    int rand_int_mac(int n);
    int rand_int_munja(int n);
    srand(time(NULL));
do{
        printf("\nHeroj ima 100 HP\nNeprijatelj ima 100 HP\n1-napad    macem(80% pogodak, 10-15 dmg\n2-napad munjom(50% pogodak, 20-30 mg))");
        scanf("%i", &oruzije);

if(oruzije==1) {

    udarac=rand_int_mac(10);
    neprijatelj=neprijatelj-udarac;
    printf("\nPogodak macem!! Neprijatelju nanosimo %i\n\n",udarac);
    if(neprijatelj < 0)
    {
        printf("Neprijatelj je porazen! Ziveo heroj!\n\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("Neprijatelju je ostalo %i\n\n",neprijatelj);
    udarac=rand_int(10);
    heroj=heroj-udarac;
    printf("Neprijatelj nanosi 10 poena stete");
    if(heroj < 0){
        printf("Neprijatelj vas je porazio!\n\n");
        break;
    }
}
else if(oruzije==2) {

    udarac=rand_int_munja(10);
    neprijatelj=neprijatelj-udarac;
    printf("\nPogodak munjom!! Nepijatelju nanosimo %i\n\n",udarac);
    if(neprijatelj < 0)
    {
        printf("Neprijatelj je porazen! Ziveo heroj!\n\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("Neprijatelju je ostalo %i\n\n",neprijatelj);
    udarac=rand_int(10);
    heroj=heroj-udarac;
    printf("Neprijatelj nanosi 10 poena stete");
    if(heroj < 0){
        printf("Neprijatelj vas je porazio!\n\n");
        break;
    }
}
}
while(1);

}}
 int rand_int_mac() (int n)  //  ERROR:NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS DOESN'T MATCH PROTOTYPE
{
return rand()%n + 10;
}
int rand_int_munja() (int n) // SAME ERROR !
{
return rand()%n + 10;
}`
```

Btw sry for my own language in code, i must send it like this. I have few questions for u

- HEROJ - HERO
- NEPRIJATELJ - ENEMY
- ORUZIJE - WEAPON
- UDARAC - HIT
- MAC - SWORD
- MUNJA - LIGHTING

so, sword need to deal 10-15 dmg and have 80% to hit and ligthing 20-30 with 50% to hit what i need to change??

Comment: For one thing, I would move `srand(time(NULL));` out of the `while` loop. Call it once at the start of the program.

Comment: I guess `int rand_int_mac() (int n)` should be `int rand_int_mac(int n)`

Comment: Not behind the downvotes, but the trigger maybe the foreign language. Either translate or use something like I just did. Btw. we speak the same language :)

Comment: On a side note, read through the basics again so you don't make mistakes like that function definitions. And enable comprehensive compiler warnings (and don't ignore them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the issues in your code. First, as suggested in the comments, you don't have to call `srand` on every iteration, just once upfront - that sets the random seed for your current program execution and here it is enough to do it once,

```
int main()
{

srand(time(NULL));
```

Secondly, you're using wrong symbols for the percent character - what you're using, a single `%` indicates type that is going to be outputted. You need to use `%%` instead,

```
printf("\nHeroj ima 100 HP\nNeprijatelj ima 100 HP\n1-napad    macem(80%% pogodak, 10-15 dmg\n2-napad munjom(50%% pogodak, 20-30 mg))");
```

Finally, you define (and declare) the functions without the extra parentheses (also, as mentioned in the comments) i.e. it's not

```
int rand_int_mac() (int n)
```

but

```
int rand_int_mac(int n)
```

Same for munja.

Also, if you want your sword damage to be between 10 and 15 you need to change your random number generator function. Currently it produces numbers between 10 and 19. To do so use

`udarac=rand_int_mac(6);`

instead of

`udarac=rand_int(10);`

This will add a number between 0 and 5 to 10 in your function `rand_int_mac` and produce damage in the target interval. For thunder it would be

```
int rand_int_munja(int n)
{
    return rand()%n + 20;
}
```

...instead of `+ 10` and should be called as `rand_int_munja(11)`.